# Pass class as function argument and reset class repeatedly within in function

Tags: python, class

In my python script I have defined a class similar to the following (admittedly bogus) class:

```
import copy


class Example:

    def __init__(self, a, b):

        self.a = a
        self.b = b

        self.__default__ = copy.deepcopy(self.__dict__)

        self.t = 0
        self.d = False

    def do(self):

        self.a += self.b - self.t
        self.t += 1
        if self.t == self.b:
            self.d = True
        return self.a

    def reset(self):

        self.__init__(**self.__default__)
```

Now, I would like to pass an instance of this class to my main function and repeatedly reset the instance to its default state. Despite having a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866587/pythonic-way-to-reset-an-objects-variables), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116090/python-class-attributes-resetting), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899454/restore-python-class-to-original-state) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45798899/preferred-way-of-resetting-a-class-in-python), I couldn't get it going. The working example below gives the desired result, yet resets the instance in the main function explicitly. The dysfunctional example is one of my many tries to make it work using a `reset` method.

```
# working example:
def main(x):

    agg = []
    for i in range(x):
        klass = Example(1, 3)
        while not klass.d:
            a = klass.do()
            agg.append(a)
    return agg

# dysfunctional example:
def main2(klass, x):

    agg = []
    for i in range(x):
        klass.reset()
        while not klass.d:
            a = klass.do()
            agg.append(a)
    return agg
```

Then `main(5)` gives

```
res = main(5)
print(res)
>>> [4, 6, 7, 4, 6, 7, 4, 6, 7, 4, 6, 7, 4, 6, 7]
```

whereas

```
ex = Example(1, 3)  # default state
res = main2(ex, 5)
print(res)
```

throws the error: `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument '__default__'`

Since I would like to avoid having to re-instantiate the class in the main script anew for different reasons, I would be grateful if someone could help me out with the `reset` method.

Comment: How do you want to magically run the functionality of the reset method without calling it?

Comment: Are you (initially) passing the object to your main function in "its default state"?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I guess I wasn't clear in the question at first. Now I do call the `reset` method in the `main2` function.

Comment: @jedwards For this example, yes. `Example(1, 3)` is the class default state.

Comment: the return agg in main2 is bad indented ?

Comment: @bboumend True, thanks.

Comment: use this in your reset : self.__init__(self.__default__['a'], self.__default__['b']).
Currently you are passing the whole dict wich contains t and d who are not in the init params

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like that:

```
class Example:

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """This stores the default state then init the instance using this default state"""
        self.__default_args__ = args
        self.__default_kwargs__ = kwargs
        self.init(*args, **kwargs)

    def do(self):
        """Do whatever you want """
        self.a += self.b - self.t
        self.t += 1
        if self.t == self.b:
            self.d = True
        return self.a

    def init(self, a, b):
        """Inits the instance to a given state"""
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.t = 0
        self.d = False
        return self

    def reset(self):
        """Resets the instance to the default (stored) state"""
        return self.init(*self.__default_args__, **self.__default_kwargs__)
```

Comment: I don't see the point in allowing `*args` and `**kwargs` in `__init__` if you pass it all to a callable with the signature `init(self, a, b)` afterwards. Any keyword argument other than `a` or `b` will raise a `TypeError`.

Comment: Just for simplification. This way you only have to update the parameters in `init()` if you want more parameters to be handled. The `TypeError` would be there as well if you define the parameters in `__init__(self, a, b)` then call the methods with unexpected args.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. +1 as it works perfectly on the example I've given you. Yet, when I try to transfer the approach to my main project, `class.reset` returns a `NoneObject`. What could be reasons for that behavior?

Comment: `.reset()` returns `None` if there is no explicit return clause. You seem to want `.reset()` to return the reset instance. Updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation using context manager:

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.t = 0
        self.d = False

    def do(self):
        self.a += self.b - self.t
        self.t += 1
        if self.t == self.b:
            self.d = True
        return self.a

    def __enter__(self):
        self._a = self.a
        self._b = self.b

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.t = 0
        self.d = False
        self.a = self._a
        self.b = self._b

def main2(klass, x):
    agg = []
    for i in range(x):
        with klass:
            while not klass.d:
                a = klass.do()
                agg.append(a)
    return agg


ex = Example(1, 3)
res = main2(ex, 5)
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

A reusable way to do this would be to implement a `Resettable` class to be inherited.

### Resettable

```
class Resettable:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.__args__ = args
        self.__kwargs__ = kwargs

    def reset(self):
        self.__init__(*self.__args__, **self.__kwargs__)
```

### Usage

Using a `property` to define an attribute that entirely depends on other attributes will also smoothen the process of resetting. This idea of having a *single source of truth* is generally a helpful paradigm for states that need to go back and forth in time.

```
class Example(Resettable):
    def __init__(self, a=0):
        self.a = a
        super().__init__(a)

    def do(self):
        self.a += 1
        return self.a

    @property
    def d(self):
        return self.a > 3 # or any other condition

def main(instance, x):
    agg = []
    for _ in range(x):
        instance.reset()
        while not instance.d:
            a = instance.do()
            agg.append(a)
    return agg

print(main(Example(), 3)) # [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

The underlying assumption of the `Resettable` class is that the arguments passed to the constructor contain all the information needed to reset, using properties make that assumption easier to satisfy.